# QGIS is filtering out the data I want to export

Tags: qgis

I am working on a project involving a lot of data, which I have to export from .dbf to CSV, but QGIS fails to do so and only exports less than half of the data.

It seems like QGIS is applying some internal filter that I cannot get rid of, as it shows that the data is filtered even when `Show All Features` is selected.

[image: Total and filtered data amounts are different]

How could I solve this?

I've already tried using python with `dbfread` and `simpledbf`, but those failed to even open the file (I guess it's because they're trying to use `dBase V` instead of `dBase III`, which this file is based on).

P.s. I am using only Linux on my system, but if there are any solutions on Windows, I would be willing to give it a try.

Comment: did you apply a filter when you imported data? look in the layer properties -> settings

Comment: try using `ogr2ogr` to do this

Comment: @IanTurton Turns out ArcGis/ArcMap export is broken to .dbf when it is exporting huge amounts of data (I think it only exports up to 4GB), so it was my data that was broken. Fixed it by exporting everything from ArcGis to .dbf in smaller batches, then QGIS and every other program works fine.